# Regular expression include the flags ignorecase and dot match all

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to define the regex to `IGNORECASE` and that the dot will match all.
The following code:

```
str = "Test "
a = re.findall(r"(\w+)", str, re.IGNORECASE, re.S)
```

get the error

```
TypeError: findall() takes at most 3 positional arguments (4 given)
```

Comment: Matt Ball is correct (+1). You can also include those flags in the regex itself, FYI: `(?i)(?s)(\d+)`.

Comment: @user1869297 What would be your expected output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Multiple flags can be specified by bitwise OR-ing them; `re.I | re.M` sets both the `I` and `M` flags, for example.

[so, bitwise-or the flags:](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html#compilation-flags)

```
str = "Test "
a = re.findall(r"(\d+)", str, re.IGNORECASE|re.S)
```

Comment: You can also add them, however `|` is safer since it won't hurt anything if you accidentally specify the same flag more than once.